# Python pandas dataframe 1 non-zero and non NaN attribute every n rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe defined in the following manner:

```
2009-11-18  500.0
2009-11-19  500.0
2009-11-20    NaN
2009-11-23  500.0
2009-11-24  500.0
2009-11-25    NaN
2009-11-27    NaN
2009-11-30    NaN
2009-12-01  500.0
2009-12-02  500.0
2009-12-03  500.0
2009-12-04  500.0
2009-12-07    NaN
2009-12-08    NaN
2009-12-09  500.0
2009-12-10  500.0
2009-12-11  500.0
2009-12-14  500.0
```

My intention is to keep one non NaN element every n rows. For example if my n is 4 I would keep 2009-11-18 500 and set everything else up to (and including) 2009-11-23 to 0, I would repeat the same for other elements of array, is there an efficient, pythonic, vectorized way of doing this?

To make this more concrete, I intend on array eventually to look like this:

```
2009-11-18  500.0
2009-11-19  0
2009-11-20  0
2009-11-23  0
2009-11-24  500.0
2009-11-25  0
2009-11-27  0
2009-11-30  0
2009-12-01  500.0
2009-12-02  0
2009-12-03  0
2009-12-04  0
2009-12-07  0
2009-12-08  0
2009-12-09  500.0
2009-12-10  0
2009-12-11  0
2009-12-14  0
```

Comment: So if length of last group is not `4`, value is omit?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use first `np.arange` with floor divison for creating groups, then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and get index of first non `NaN` value by [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html). Last get `0` by [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html) if not contains values of `a`:

```
print (np.arange(len(df.index)) // 4)
[0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4]

idx = df.col.groupby([np.arange(len(df.index)) // 4]).idxmin()
print (idx)
0   2009-11-18
1   2009-11-24
2   2009-12-01
3   2009-12-09
4   2009-12-11
Name: col, dtype: datetime64[ns]

df.col = df.col.where(df.index.isin(idx), 0)
print (df)
              col
2009-11-18  500.0
2009-11-19    0.0
2009-11-20    0.0
2009-11-23    0.0
2009-11-24  500.0
2009-11-25    0.0
2009-11-27    0.0
2009-11-30    0.0
2009-12-01  500.0
2009-12-02    0.0
2009-12-03    0.0
2009-12-04    0.0
2009-12-07    0.0
2009-12-08    0.0
2009-12-09  500.0
2009-12-10    0.0
2009-12-11  500.0
2009-12-14    0.0
```

Solution if length of last group is not `4`, last values is omiting:

```
arr = np.arange(len(df.index)) // 4
print (arr)
[0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4]

#if equal by last value of array substract 1
arr1 = np.where(arr == arr[-1], arr[-1] - 1, arr)
print (arr1)
[0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3]

idx = df.col.groupby(arr1).idxmin()
print (idx)
0   2009-11-18
1   2009-11-24
2   2009-12-01
3   2009-12-09
Name: col, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

```
df.col = df.col.where(df.index.isin(idx), 0)
print (df)
              col
2009-11-18  500.0
2009-11-19    0.0
2009-11-20    0.0
2009-11-23    0.0
2009-11-24  500.0
2009-11-25    0.0
2009-11-27    0.0
2009-11-30    0.0
2009-12-01  500.0
2009-12-02    0.0
2009-12-03    0.0
2009-12-04    0.0
2009-12-07    0.0
2009-12-08    0.0
2009-12-09  500.0
2009-12-10    0.0
2009-12-11    0.0
2009-12-14    0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC
You restart your counter when you get your next value.  In this case, I'd use a generator.  Not vectorized!

```
def next4(s):
    idx = s.first_valid_index()
    while idx is not None:
        loc = s.index.get_loc(idx)
        yield s.loc[[idx]]
        idx = s.iloc[loc+4:].first_valid_index()

pd.concat(next4(df[1])).reindex(df.index, fill_value=0).to_frame()
```

[image]